# Iron Router parse posted values

Tags: meteor, iron-router, body-parser

I am currently trying to catch posted values from form inside specific route rule.
Since all the other SO posts about this do not work I wanted to ask again.Do you have this sorted out and implemented in your projects?
Is there a solution for Iron-Router@1.0.9?

```
this.request.body
```

Above code inside route rule always returns undefined.

```
 Router.route('/register', function(){
   console.log( JSON.stringify(this.request.body) );
   //this.render('test',{data:{data:this.request.body.username}})

 });







//SERVER ONLY
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    'addSong': function(songName) {
      var userId = Meteor.userId()
      songs.insert({
        userId: userId,
        name: songName
      })
    }

  })

  Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

}
```

Comment: I guess this is for server side can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

The iron router guide [lets us know](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#creating-routes) that `this.request` and `this.response` are "NodeJS request and response objects".

If you take a look at some documentation for [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body), you will find that:

> By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use
>   body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer.

From [Iron-router's guide](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-hooks-and-connect):

> IR makes express' body-parser available at Iron.Router.bodyParser.

So there you have it! If you want `this.request.body` to be populated, you should maybe add:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(Iron.Router.bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created one file for my controller to maintain code re-usability name as solar.js under controller folder that solar file has my db functionality and pass the request and response as parameter for that file like exports.getSolarInfo = (req,res) => { console.log(req.body) }, here your will get ur body paramter.then manipulate our functionality here then send response like response = { "status" : 0, "result" : "invalid query" } res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

// importing controller
    const SOLAR = require('./controllers/solar.js');

```
Router.route( '/solar', function() {
  //setting header type to allow cross origin
  this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*' );
  if ( this.request.method === "OPTIONS" ) {
    this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' );
    this.response.setHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS' );
    this.response.end( 'Set OPTIONS.' );
  } else {
    SOLAR.getSolarInfo(this.request,this.response);
  }
}, { where: 'server' });
```

Comment: While this code snippet might solve the issue and provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please consider an [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @ButchMonkey I have created one file for my controller to maintain code re-usability name as solar.js under controller folder that solar file has my db functionality  and pass the request and response as parameter for that file like  exports.getSolarInfo = (req,res) => {  console.log(req.body) }, here your will get ur body paramter.then manipulate our functionality here then send response like                         
       response = {
                        "status" : 0,
                        "result"  : "invalid query"
                      }
          res.end(JSON.stringify(response));

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of commenting so that users can easily understand what your code does.